# Анимация для Inner HTML (Anime.js или альтернативы)

Tags: javascript, анимация, inner

Мне нужно сделать калькулятор для рассчёта стоимости видеоролика. Есть такой код:

```js
function calc() {
  //получаем ссылку на элемент Select (Тип дизайна)
  var type_design = document.getElementById("type_design");
  //получаем ссылку на чекбокс (Требуется верстка?)
  var is_html = document.getElementById("is_html");
  //получаем ссылку на элемент input (Кол-во вариантов)
  var count = document.getElementById("count");
  //получаем ссылку на элемент span, в него будем писать стоимость дизайна
  var result = document.getElementById("result");

  var price = 0;
  price += parseInt(type_design.options[type_design.selectedIndex].value);
  price += (is_html.checked == true) ? parseInt(is_html.value) : 0;
  price = parseInt(count.value) * price;

  result.innerHTML = price;
}
```

```html
<select onchange="calc()" id="type_design">
      <option value="0">Выбрать</option>
      <option value="5000">Простой дизайн сайта</option>
      <option value="7000">Сложный дизайн сайта</option>
      <option value="10000">Дизайн интернет-магазина</option>
    </select><br/>
<input type="checkbox" onchange="calc()" value="3000" id="is_html" />
<label for="is_html">Требуется верстка?</label>
<br/> Кол-во вариантов: <input type="text" id="count" value="1" onchange="calc()" />
<div>Стоимость дизайна сайта:
  <div id="result">0</div> руб.</div>
```

Он отлично считает, но мне необходимо анимировать увеличение/уменьшение итоговой стоимости. 
Пробовал использовать [Anime.js](http://animejs.com/). Вроде бы там просто всё в примерах, но у меня не получается.

Answer (score 1):

Я уже самостоятельно нашёл ответ :)
Кому интересно:

```js
function calc() {
  //получаем ссылку на элемент Select (Тип дизайна)
  var type_design = document.getElementById("type_design");
  //получаем ссылку на чекбокс (Требуется верстка?)
  var is_html = document.getElementById("is_html");
  //получаем ссылку на элемент input (Кол-во вариантов)
  var count = document.getElementById("count");
  //получаем ссылку на элемент span, в него будем писать стоимость дизайна
  var result = document.getElementById("result");

  var price = 0;
  price += parseInt(type_design.options[type_design.selectedIndex].value);
  price += (is_html.checked == true) ? parseInt(is_html.value) : 0;
  price = parseInt(count.value) * price;

  $.Tween.propHooks.number = {
    get: function(tween) {
      var num = tween.elem.innerHTML.replace(/^[^\d-]+/, '');
      return parseFloat(num) || 0;
    },

    set: function(tween) {
      var opts = tween.options;
      tween.elem.innerHTML = (opts.prefix || '') +
        tween.now.toFixed(opts.fixed || 0) +
        (opts.postfix || '');
    }
  };

  $('#result').animate({
    number: price
  }, 'slow');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select onchange="calc()" id="type_design">
      <option value="0">Выбрать</option>
      <option value="5000">Простой дизайн сайта</option>
      <option value="7000">Сложный дизайн сайта</option>
      <option value="10000">Дизайн интернет-магазина</option>
    </select><br/>
<input type="checkbox" onchange="calc()" value="3000" id="is_html" />
<label for="is_html">Требуется верстка?</label>
<br/> Кол-во вариантов: <input type="text" id="count" value="1" onchange="calc()" />
<div>Стоимость дизайна сайта:
  <div id="result">0</div> руб.</div>
```

Comment: Вместо onchange практичнее будет использовать oninput